# In Android create only one instance of a Class

Tags: java, android

I'm experimenting with `PhoneStateListener` and I'm having problems being able to turn the Listener off. In my code, I create a new instance of my `TeleListener` class which is extending the `PhoneStateListener`. In order to turn the Listener off, I need to call the same instance of my `TeleListener` Class that I called initially. But the code as I have written it is creating a new instance, not using the existing instance. So my question is, **how can I write it so that initially, a new instance is called, then when I want to turn the Listener off, I call the original instance?** I'm using a switch to turn the Listener on and off, so here's the switch code as it looks now:

```
    // ---
    TeleMan = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    // --- END

    // --- switch
    switch_SW = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.mainSwitch_SW);
    switch_SW.setTextOn("ON");
    switch_SW.setTextOff("OFF");

    // --- get switch prefs
    switchPref = getSharedPreferences(SWITCH_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    switch_SW.setChecked(switchPref.getBoolean(switchKeyStr, true));

    switch_SW.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {

                // ---
                TeleMan.listen(tListen, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor swEditor = getSharedPreferences(
                        SWITCH_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                swEditor.putBoolean(switchKeyStr, true);
                swEditor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ON",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // --- END
            } else {

                // ---
                TeleMan.listen(tListen, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);

                SharedPreferences.Editor swEditor = getSharedPreferences(
                        SWITCH_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                swEditor.putBoolean(switchKeyStr, false);
                swEditor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OFF",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // ---
            }

        }
    });// --- END switch
```

I'm creating the instance of the Listener here:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SwitchCompat switch_SW;

SharedPreferences switchPref;
TelephonyManager TeleMan;

public static final String SWITCH_PREFS = "switchPref";
public static final String switchKeyStr = "switchKey";
new instance --> private TeleListener tListen = new TeleListener();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

... and then I go into the above Switch code...

Comment: declare a public static variable . if its null , init it else skip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [Java Singleton Class Design](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html).

If you have done according this pattern, you would then use it like this:

```
TeleMan.getInstance().method();
//                      ^--- This could be any methods you've defined
//                           in this singleton.
```

Note that all references returned by `TeleMan.getInstance()` point to a same memory location.

```
TeleMan tm1 = TeleMan.getInstance();
TeleMan tm2 = TeleMan.getInstance();
TeleMan tm3 = TeleMan.getInstance();

tm1 == tm2 == tm3
```

Comment: This is the "clear and nice" way to do it, this is using patterns to look like a pro and keep good practices, since is still encapsulating the functinality as an object and not as some interdependient static procedural methods +1 for this

Answer (score 0):

Srinath Ganesh is correct! When I declare the `TeleListener` variable, I changed it from private to public static like so:

```
        public static TeleListener tListen;

    ...

    tListen = new TeleListener();
    TeleMan.listen(tListen = new TeleListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor swEditor = getSharedPreferences(
            SWITCH_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    swEditor.putBoolean(switchKeyStr, true);
    swEditor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ON",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Now toggling the switch will enable and disable the Listener Class.

Answer (score 0):

Even though `static` would solve the issue, I find that approach as [smelly code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Instead, consider keeping it the way it is and adding the respective logic to attach the listener inside `onResume()` or `onStart()` callback; and detaching `tListen` inside `onPause()` or `onStop()` callback methods (depending on the shared preference, of course flag)